# Error on Azure YAML pipeline cannot complete deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

In my YAML pipeline I get the error: ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/a/**/*.zip
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

It is a two stage build / deploy YAML pipeline.

My Pipeline is as follows:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages: 
- stage: BuildIt
  jobs:
  - job: BuildTheCode
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build
      displayName: 'npm install and build'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: true
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: Deploy
  jobs: 
    - job: PublishCode
      steps: 
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'
          appType: 'webAppLinux'
          WebAppName: 'xxxxxx'
          packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

I am new to YAML Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to [download your artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#download-artifacts) first:

```
- stage: Deploy
  jobs: 
    - job: PublishCode
      steps: 
      - download: current
        artifact: drop
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'
          appType: 'webAppLinux'
          WebAppName: 'xxxxxx'
          packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/**/*.zip'
```

Comment: Do you need to change the `packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/**/*.zip'` path also?

Comment: yes, you will also have to change the path

Comment: I do get this error though: 
Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: C:\Builds\xxxxx\_work\28\drop\**\*.zip. Please restrain the search pattern.

Comment: Can you try to specify the path like this: `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) which:

- automatically download all available artifacts
- gives you control via environment restrictions

In your case it would be like

```
- deployment: DeployWeb
  displayName: deploy Web App
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  environment: 'smarthotel-dev'
  strategy:
    # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
          inputs:
            ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
            azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'
            appType: 'webAppLinux'
            WebAppName: 'xxxxxx'
            packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

However, you may need to create first the environment `smarthotel-dev`.

Here is full yaml:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages: 
- stage: BuildIt
  jobs:
  - job: BuildTheCode
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build
      displayName: 'npm install and build'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: true
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: Deploy
  jobs: 
    - deployment: DeployWeb
      displayName: deploy Web App
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      environment: 'smarthotel-dev'
      strategy:
        # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'
                appType: 'webAppLinux'
                WebAppName: 'xxxxxx'
                packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Comment: IMHO yes, because deployment jobs are designed for that part - for deploying app. You could use nev restrctions like a gate approval and more. For more envs it is really important. You could also do sequential deployments etc. There is more stuff just for controlling deployments.

Comment: Can you update the answer with the complete pipeline, so I can see where it goes in stages?

Comment: Yeah, I just did it.

Comment: Can you just explain what the `environment: 'xxxx'` refers to? So you need to create the environment in DevOps first? Is there another way without the need of doing this?

Comment: This is [the environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops). Bascially you don't need to have there any reources, you can use an empty one and benefit from the control it provides you for deployments.

Comment: I can see what you mean, although I want to try and do this without adding environments as I may not have permission to add it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use deployment jobs without environments.